# XSL FO inline alignment on an existing sort/conditional XSL

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I need to get right-align and left-align working in the same line. Looking over similar responses, I found the below recommendation,

```
<fo:block text-align-last="justify">
  LEFT TEXT (want this to be the Contacts element from the below)
  <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
  RIGHT TEXT (want this to be the Address1 element from the below)
</fo:block>
```

But when I try to apply it to my existing XSL code (see below) I can’t make it work – I don’t know enough about how to edit it to accommodate/merge both the sort/conditionals and the FO.  Can someone help me get this right?

Exsiting/working code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!-- DWXMLSource="XML - Builder Members.xml" -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">]>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <memberdata>  
      <xsl:for-each select="memberdata/memberinfo">
        <xsl:sort select="SortKey"/>
        <memberdata>
          <xsl:if test="Contacts[.!='']">
            <Contacts><xsl:value-of select="Contacts" /></Contacts>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="Address1[.!='']">
            <Address1><xsl:value-of select="Address1" /></Address1>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </memberdata>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </memberdata> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XSLT code does not contain `<fo:block>`, it's not clear to me what you want to do.

Comment: @Tom: Without a desired output this is not a real question.

Comment: It's not a well-defined question.

Answer (score 0):

Independently of the actual answer to your question (which is impossible to give in the current form the question is in), I'd like to suggest a few improvements to your general approach to XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="memberdata">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="memberinfo">
        <xsl:sort select="SortKey" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="memberinfo">
    <memberdata>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Contacts" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Address1" />
    </memberdata>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Contacts|Address1">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space() != ''">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- Avoid `<xsl:for-each>`, use distinct templates and `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead. This results in cleaner, less duplicated and less deeply nested code. It also could result in more efficient processing of your stylesheet, as XSLT processors are optimized for template matching and can parallelize template execution.
- Note that you can use the same template for multiple elements, see third template above.
- Avoid adding line-breaks via such a construct: `<xsl:text>

  </xsl:text>`. Doing this destroys source code readability and is prone to errors as soon as the source code is formatted *(I've already done this in your question to be able to indent your code properly in the first place)*. Use character references `&#10;` instead to separate source code layout and output layout.
- Note that you can use `<xsl:copy-of>` to make a copy of an element, no need to do `<foo><xsl:value-of select="foo" /></foo>`.

Comment: Tomalak thx but it's resulting in 2 separate line items when imported to InDesign CS5, all left-aligned.

Comment: There are two separate questions here: (a) what output you need from the stylesheet, and (b) how to get the stylesheet to produce the output specified in (a). Your comment about InDesign suggests you are not sure about (a). If so, you need to get that straightened out before you can hope to get any useful answers to (b).

Answer (score 0):

Taking your request at face value, this seems to be what you're asking for, which merges the sort, the conditionals and the FO.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!-- DWXMLSource="XML - Builder Members.xml" -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">]>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <memberdata>  
      <xsl:for-each select="memberdata/memberinfo">
        <xsl:sort select="SortKey"/>
        <memberdata>
          <fo:block text-align-last="justify">
            <xsl:if test="Contacts[.!='']">
              <Contacts><xsl:value-of select="Contacts" /></Contacts>
              <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
            <xsl:if test="Address1[.!='']">
              <Address1><xsl:value-of select="Address1" /></Address1>
              <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
          </fo:block>
        </memberdata>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </memberdata> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However it seems unlikely that you really want to mix `<fo:*>` elements and other elements (`<memberdata>`) in your output... unless you plan to process them later to produce a full FO document. So the above may not be quite the solution you need.

(See also @Tomalak's good points about how to improve the XSLT. I would differ with him only on the question of for-each vs. apply-templates... it really depends on several factors and what your priorities are.)

Comment: LarsH thx when i try validating your code in dreamweaver i get the following error message: 
The prefix 'fo' has not been mapped to any URI[xml]
What to do?

Comment: @Tom, indeed the XSLT I gave you was not well-formed XML. Apologies. However if you plan to be developing stylesheets, you're going to need to learn the basics of namespace declarations. Since the namespace prefix 'fo' has not been declared, you need to add a declaration for it, usually on the xsl:stylesheet element: `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" ...>`